# Why does the JS not scrolls when the position is static?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a navigation bar and I cannot get to the position where the user clicked the toggle icon, the scroll position starts from the top and not from the asked place.

The following is my JS code.
And the problem occurs in the else condition.

I can't even find whether the problem is of JavaScript or CSS.

Code is:

```
// The following are the element selectors.
const toggleButton = document.querySelector(".toggle.button");
const toggleIcon = document.querySelector(".toggle.button > .toggle__icon");
const menuContainer = document.querySelector('.header > .header__container .header__menu-container');

// Make variable in Global Scope to save scroll position of user.
let scrollPosition = 0;

// Start of the Event Listener.
toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {

    // Check if the navigation bar is expanded.
    if (!menuContainer.classList.contains("header__menu-container--open")) {

        // Toggle the following classes when the toggle icon is clicked.
        menuContainer.classList.add("header__menu-container--open");
        toggleIcon.classList.add("toggle__icon--clicked");


        // Record the scrolled position of the user.
        scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;

        // Add the fixed position and adjust the top offset to make up for the body margin.
        document.body.style.position = 'fixed';
        document.body.style.top = `-${scrollPosition}px`;

    } else {

        // Remove the fixed position and adjust the top offset to move the page to the previous scroll position.
        document.body.style.position = "";
        alert(scrollPosition); // returns the scrollposition to here
        window.scrollBy(0, scrollPosition);

        // Toggle the following classes when the toggle icon is clicked.
        menuContainer.classList.remove("header__menu-container--open");
        toggleIcon.classList.remove("toggle__icon--clicked");

    }
});
```

Even when I do this in the else block the scroll position starts from the top and not from the asked value.

```
document.body.style.position = "static";
window.scrollTo(0, 250);
```

If there are any other ways to make this work, let me know.
Thank you for staying to the end.
Thank you!